# How can I solve TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBalance')?

Tags: ether, ethers.js, hardhat

TL;DR

I'm using ethers v6.7.0

`const startingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target)`

lines using `provider.getBalance` are creating the problem.

```js
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")

describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    const sendValue = ethers.parseEther("1")
    beforeEach(async function () {
        //deploy the contract
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer,
        )
    })
    describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function () {
            const response = await fundMe.priceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.target)
        })
    })

    describe("fund", async function () {
        it("Fails if you don't send enough ETH", async function () {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.reverted // revertedWith does not work
        })
        it("updated the amount funded data structure", async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue.toString() })
            const response = await fundMe.addressToAmountFunded(deployer)
            assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString())
        })

        it("Adds funders to the array of funders", async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
            const funder = await fundMe.funders(0)
            assert.equal(funder, deployer)
        })
    })

    describe("withdraw", async function () {
        beforeEach(async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
        })

        it("withdraw ETH from a single founder", async function () {
            // Arrange
            const startingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.target,
            )

            const startingDeployerBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                deployer,
            )

            // Act
            const transactionResponse = await fundMe.withdraw()
            const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
            const endingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.target,
            )

            const endingDeployerBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                deployer,
            )
            // Assert

            assert.equal(endingFundMeBalance, 0)
            assert.equal(
                startingFundMeBalance.add(startingDeployerBalance),
                endingDeployerBalance.add(GasCost).toString(),
            )
        })
    })
})
```

```
1 failing

  1) FundMe
       withdraw
         withdraw ETH from a single founder:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBalance')
```

FundMe.sol:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


// Pragma
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


// Imports
import "./PriceConverter.sol";


// Error codes
error FundMe__NotOwner();


/**
 * @title A contract for crowd funding
 * @author Anonymous
 * @notice This contract is to demo a sample funding contract
 * @dev not now
 */
contract FundMe {
     using PriceConverter for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    
    address public /* immutable */ owner;
    uint256 public constant MINIMUM_USD = 50 * 1e18;

    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

        constructor(address priceFeedAddress) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        require(
            msg.value.getConversionRate(priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD,
            "Didn't send enough!"
        );
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] = msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        for (
            uint256 funderIndex = 0;
            funderIndex < funders.length;
            funderIndex = funderIndex + 1
        ) {
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);

        //# TRANSFER
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);

    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        // require(msg.sender == i_owner, "Sender is not owner!");
        if (msg.sender != owner) {
            revert FundMe__NotOwner();
        }
        _;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the "fund me" smart contract code as well? If `getBalance(address)` is a function in the contract, you could try removing the `.provider` from the function call

Comment: @RohanNero I just added it.
removing .provider does not work
getBalance is not a contract function

Comment: Awesome thank you! I've added an answer based on your contract's code

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is likely because you are using a different version of ethers.

You could try changing your test's lines from this:

```js
const startingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target)
```

To this:

```js
const startingFundMeBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target)
```

Or if you want to view the ETH balances of users inside your contract, either by your public mapping `addressToAmountFunded`, or just the total balances, you can create a new function to do so.

To view the values inside of the `addressToAmountFunded` mapping, you could create a function like this:

```js
function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint256) {
return addressToAmountFunded[addr];
}
```

To view entire ETH balances you could make a function like this:

```js
function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint256) {
return addr.balance;
```

Or an alternative method to view only the contract's balance would look like this:

```js
function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
return address(this).balance;
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not about making a contract call. I'm following a tutorial where it uses ethers v5 and uses fundMe.provider.getBalance() but there are no getBalance in the solidity file of the tutorial.

getBalance is included in ethers v5 and v6

anyway the working v5 source is this: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-fund-me-fcc

I'm just trying to call getBalance in ethers js v6

Comment: @ch9xy Sorry I understand now, the easiest fix would be to change your ethers version inside your package.json to `5.5.3` to match the tutorial's repo. Another solution you could try would be to change your getBalance lines like this: `const bal = ethers.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target)`

Comment: It does not work but thanks for the effort.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to get the ethers balance from `ethers.provider`?